# "Connected" even when wifi is off

Tags: java, android, connection, android-connectivitymanager

Mission is to check if the mobile is connected on internet or not. I have problem.
It shows "Connected" even when wifi is off. Here is my class.

```
public class InterneProvjera {
    Context context;
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public InterneProvjera(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (NetworkInfo i: info) {
                    if (i.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is in the main activity :

```
InterneProvjera interneProvjera = new InterneProvjera(this);
        String tKonekcija = (interneProvjera.isNetworkAvailable()) ?  "Connected" : "No connection";
        txtIspis.setText(tKonekcija);
```

Sorry if its trivial question im new in android programming. 
Ps: is there any Connection listener and how to check internet signal strength (3G, 4G, wifi)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) to check the network status using [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager)

Below is the code to check in your activity if network is connected or not. If connected, it will show you name of network in `Toast`:

**ConnectivityStatusReceiver.java**

```
public class ConnectivityStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetworkInfo != null) {
      Toast.makeText(context, activeNetworkInfo.getTypeName() + " connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet or Network connection available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ConnectivityStatusReceiver connectivityStatusReceiver;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectivityStatusReceiver = new ConnectivityStatusReceiver();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(connectivityStatusReceiver, intentFilter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (connectivityStatusReceiver != null) {
      // unregister receiver
      unregisterReceiver(connectivityStatusReceiver);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JKLHSDFJKL I have added the complete code. Hope it helped you.